# Dataframe filtered on vector and return group of match

Tags: r, filter

Probably a simple solution but could not find an elegant way. In following `df` I want to find values based on a vector and return not only the match but also the whole group the match is in.

```
df <- data.frame(group= c("a","a","b","b","b","c","d","d"),
                  person = c("Tom","Jerry","Tom","Anna","Sam","Nic","Anna","Jerry"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

search_vector <- c("Tom","Nic")
```

Expected output

```
df_result
  group person
1     a    Tom
2     a  Jerry
3     b    Tom
4     b   Anna
5     b    Sam
6     c    Nic
```

One could of course do it in two steps but there should be a better way

```
df_sub <- subset(df, person %in% search_vector)
df_result <- subset(df, group %in% df_subset$group)
```

**Edit 1**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(

  dplyr_test= df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(any(person %in% search_vector)),
  base= df[ave(df$person %in% search_vector, df$group, FUN=any),],
  convoluted = df[df$group %in% df$group[df$person %in% search_vector],],
  times = 100

)


Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 dplyr_test 3191.893 3433.7885 3736.42618 3649.4145 3991.2770 5017.041   100
       base  131.175  150.0395  193.04807  184.2435  224.6185  367.780   100
 convoluted   43.726   52.0120   68.80326   61.0035   86.0395  123.770   100
```

Comment: Not sure what the exact etiquette is as all the answers solve the problem. While elegance is subject to personal preference, the benchmark indicates an efficiency advantage of @Abdou answer. I therefore accept his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use a somewhat intricate (but efficient) set of indexing:

```
df[df$group %in% df$group[df$person %in% search_vector],]
```

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'group' variable then `filter` for `any` 'person' that are `%in%` the 'search_vector'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(any(person %in% search_vector))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could use `ave` with `any` and then use the result forlogical indexing.

```
df[ave(df$person %in% search_vector, df$group, FUN=any),]
  group person
1     a    Tom
2     a  Jerry
3     b    Tom
4     b   Anna
5     b    Sam
6     c    Nic
```